# Using expect to log in and issue a command

Tags: expect

Can you tell me why this Expect script shows me a calendar in loop mode?
I only want to see one calendar.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set fid [open /Users/john/secret]
set password [read $fid]
close $fid

spawn ssh [lindex $argv 0]@[lindex $argv 1]
expect {
-re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
send "yes\n"
exp_continue
}

"*?assword:*" {
send $password
send "\n"
exp_continue
}

"*$*" {
send "cal\r"
exp_continue
}

"*$*" {
send "exit\r"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems wrong to me

```
"*$*" {
send "cal\r"
exp_continue
}

"*$*" {
send "exit\r"
}
```

The check for a dollar sign is at the same level so after you send `cal\r` you loop and it will look for `$` again and issue `cal\r` again not reaching the last `"*$*" {`

You might have been going for this?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set fid [open /Users/john/secret]
set password [read $fid]
close $fid

spawn ssh [lindex $argv 0]@[lindex $argv 1]
expect {
    -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
        send "yes\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*?assword:*" {
        send $password
        send "\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "*$*" {
        send "cal\r"
        expect "*$*" {
            send "exit\r"
        }
    }
}
```

You should notice that I have nested the second check for a `$` inside the check for the first. I also assume you left off a closing bracket at the bottom of your original question?